# Python: How to get foreground processes

Tags: python, windows, process

I wish to get all the processes showing on the Task Manager Apps, i use this code to get all the processes:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'WMIC PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
if b'Program' in line:
    print(line)
```

How can i distinct between the "Background processes" (showing of the task manager) and the "App"?

[image: The image]